How to prove a problem is EXP hard
Summary of the problem:  Given an alternating time turing machine ($M$), a polynomial $p(.)$ and a string ($w$), is it EXPhard to find if  $M$ accepts $w$ using not more than $p(|M|+|w|)$ space?
My work:  I have a problem I would like to prove is EXPTIME hard. I have a couple of reductions to do so. One is reduction from combinatorial EXP complete games but is hard to read.
The other is a reduction from alternate poly space Turing machine. But instead of taking as input a turing machine ($M$) and a string ($w$) to check for acceptance, it takes as input a turing machine ($M$), a string ($w$) and a polynomial $p(.)$ which gives the amount of space the turing machine is allowed to use. Is this reasonable to do?
Possible solution:  Ideally I would like to write a reduction from an exphard problem to alternate turing machine with a polynomial and string. to prove that this problem is hard as well.

What do you mean by "alternating time"? What time has to do with alternation?

This is an immediate consequence of the fact that $\text{APSPACE} = \text{EXPTIME}$ (see, for example, here). Specifically,
consider a language in $L \in \text{EXPTIME}$, and let $T$ be an alternating TM that decides $L$ in space $s(n)$, where $s:\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ is some polynomial. Then, a reduction from $L$ to your problem operates as follows. Given input $x$ for the reduction, the reduction outputs $\langle T, x, s(|x|)\rangle$. As $T$ decides $L$ with space-complexity $s(n)$, it holds that $x\in L$ iff $T$ accepts $x$ while using at most $s(|x|)$ tape-cells.
Note that $T$ is a constant (does not depend on the input $x$). Therefore, the reduction is computable in polynomial-time as it simply outputs the description of $T$, copies $x$, and computes $s(|x|)$.
